# How to store email conversations on Salesforce?

Tags: email, file-storage

By "conversations" I mean the process of sending and receiving emails on the platform. Imagine a situation where you have a commerce running on Salesforce, and an employee needs to contact a supplier using email.

Naturally the platform is able to send the email, with templates, attachments, etc. But when the email is answered by the supplier, is it possible to get this email stored on the same record it was fired from? Is it possible for the user to respond that email from within the platform? What about possible attachments on the supplier's email?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now that I know you don't have any email service integrations, what you'd want to do is create an inbound email service to use for a "reply to" email address with your "outbound emails" which could send either through normal Salesforce emails (I think you can use a different reply to, but would need to check) or with the service that you've configured. When the reply comes back in, you'd then need to parse it and determine which account/activity/contact it was related to and attach it to that record before forwarding it to the correct user (the user who sent it originally). This would be the basic approach to use in your situation.

Be aware of a few caveats about this approach. Going outbound, the email address can be made to look as though it's coming from your company although it's actually being sent from a Salesforce Server. The "reply to" inbound handler email address looks like a long string of letters followed by an `@salesforce.com`. It isn't "pretty" to look at and might appear rather confusing to your recipients. Some recipients might have issues both with it coming from Salesforce and not directly from your company. They may especially have concerns about who it's being returned to. Email of this kind is frequently misidentified as spam by servers as "spoofed email" when it's not.

From a Salesforce user perspective, for a more sophisticated solution, you'd want to find the original attachment, open it, and then append the reply to it before re-saving the attachment as an incremental version of the original. You could potentially use this same interface as a way of writing and saving your reply to the incoming email reply. This is the way that I'd personally do it instead of just using the standard email object.

I prefer this approach because it offers the potential to preserve the message threading. Saving lots of different attachments doesn't necessarily do that. I've seen document readers and writers written in Apex that have this functionality (we have one that we use for a different purpose).

Hope this helps give you some ideas.